# Fubini Tonneli Theorems

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The next are brought from Folland's Pure and Applied Mathematics.

I'm a little bit confused about the different demands in Fubini and Tonneli theorems.
Folland defined x- section of function $f$ on product space $X \times Y$ , denoted by $f^x$ , as the one varibale function on $Y$ , defined as $f^x(y)=f(x,y)$. He have proved that this function is measurable with the $\sigma$ algebra on $Y$, whenever $f(x,y)$ measurable w.r.t to the product measure.

In Tonneli theorem, we assume that our function f is non negative, integrable function on $X \times Y$. We condluded that $f^x$ is integrable , i.e $\int f^x(y) d\mu (y)$ exists. I think that this induced from the fact that our function is non-negative, and for restricted domain of integrating, the integral exists.

In Fubbini's theorem, we ask $f(x,y)$ to be integrable on $X\times Y$, and we asked that $f^x$ will be integrable as well. Why do we have to ask that as well?